# Very strange error code

Tags: php

I have a script that used to work. Now that I've uploaded it, it responded:

```
[06-Jan-2014 13:23:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
[06-Jan-2014 13:23:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
[06-Jan-2014 13:23:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
[06-Jan-2014 13:25:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
[06-Jan-2014 13:25:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
[06-Jan-2014 13:26:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
[06-Jan-2014 13:26:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/statsaff/public_html/customforthisdomain.php on line 165
```

Upon further investigation, I found out:

1. the error is exactly the same no matter how I modify `customforthisdomain.php`
2. In fact, I have arranged that line 165 in the script is empty
3. The error only shows up on Firefox. The script run fine on internet explorer.

This is the code around line 165, which is empty

```
function mainURL()
{
    $domain=getDomain();

    $dictionary=getDomainDictionary();
    return $dictionary[MAINURL];
}

//..

function getDomainDictionary()
```

Line 165 is within that empty space.

What drives me nut is the error is said to happen on line 165. However, there is NOTHING on line 165. No matter how I change the script the error message keeps saying that it happens on line 165.

I split the file into 2 files. Then I start moving code from one file to another.

The culprit seems to be in this line

```
function getDomain()
{
    $domain=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $domain = str_replace("www.", "", $domain);

    /*if ($_GET['asdomain'])
    {
        $domain=$_GET['asdomain'];
    }*/
    return $domain;
}
```

If I uncomment the commented line then the error is in customdomain1.php. If I comment it, the error is in getcountryotherway.php

The culprit line is always 165. That is despite the fact that the file does not even contain 165 lines.

Comment: adjust memory_limit in php.ini

Comment: What does the script do?

Comment: Technically speaking it shouldn't matter which browser you're in; you should post some code as, all we can tell from here is: **It's out of memory**

Comment: @JimThio if it's always on line 165, and that's not changing despite changing, probably means you're not changing the actual *uploaded* file on the server - if you're using Filezilla, this might ask you to overwrite the server file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to mess up here.  First is that the cache is configured wrongly.  In SilverStripe installations silverstripe-cache has to exist.    This site is quite relevant.

www.meerware.com/thoughts/2013/07/choose-your-silverstripe-cache-location-carefully/

Your php may have a different cache, but cache not being writable causes infinite memory consumption.

In addition one can have the same issue if selinux or a permissions issue prevents the cache location from being writeable.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for that error:

- Script uses too much memory
- Wrong / Infinite loops like while, foreach, for
- Cached files may cause that too

If you can not change your server's php configuration, you have to analyze your code and do some improvements.

Browsers should not give a problem because of server's configuration. Maybe clear your cache and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Update PHP.ini or use init_set to change limit.

```
 ini_set("memory_limit","12M");
```

12Mo is limit.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Some of the function keep recursively call each other. I have since fixed that. Don't know why it always says that the error is in line 165. There is nothing in line 165. That's grossly misleading.